# I'm getting a null return error from trying to load in a png image

Tags: java, image, rendering

So I've been following a tutorial and am getting stuck on creating an image loader. The idea is to make a thing that will directly read from the class path, where I put a folder named "res" for resources.
The main function inside the image loader class is `return ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getResource(path));` and I'm calling it with `testImage = ImageLoader.loadImage("/textures/Test.png");`, (textures is inside of it). I'm not really sure why it's not working, and I don't get any errors until it's run, at which point I get:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
```

and a few other lines pointing to where in my program it might have an issue.

Comment: Perhaps you search your question before posting, because there are many similar questions with answers already. Check the **Related** sidebar on this page.

Comment: I have attempted to go through a dozen or so, but the answers aren't helpful. I've gotten through most of the steps on them. Could you perhaps point me towards one that would be helpful?

Comment: After several hours of the standard headache of debugging, I discovered that if I just made a new folder and changed it to a source folder from right clicking it rather than from adding it to the build path, it would work. Phew!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that if I just made a new folder and changed it to a source folder from right clicking it rather than from adding it to the build path, it would work. I think the original problem was from clicking the project folder and adding it in from there; I was following a tutorial that did that and it seems that Eclipse may have updated since then since I went back and double checked that section several times. Hope this helps anyone else who may be following something like that!